# Plotting intermediate values of an argument in a recursive function

Tags: recursion, visualization, debugging, monitoring

I've read through the documentation on [tuning and debugging](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TuningAndDebugging.html) but feel like I am missing some important concepts. Many of the examples given presume the programmer is explicitly generating ranges of values for a symbolic variable. For example, on the [Reap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) documentation page, we have this canonical example:

```
Reap[Sum[Sow[i^2] + 1, {i, 10}]]
```

Here, the [Sow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.htm) and [Reap](http://ttps://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) functions work together to collect intermediate states of the calculation `i*i`, where `i` is set to iterate from 1-10. No problems here, as the variable is a symbol (i) and its iteration bounds are set in the expression.

However, there are other approaches to writing expressions, including recursive definitions where a single value will be passed in to a variable and it may be useful to monitor that variable as it is transformed throughout the recursive calculation.

For example, given a homemade `gcd` function based on the [Euclidean approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid's_algorithm):

```
gcd[x_, y_] := If [Equal[y, 0], x, gcd[y, Mod[x, y]]]
```

We can trace this function as follows:

[image: Output of Trace]

However, that output is a bit verbose and cannot be immediately graphed (as far as I know). I've tried [Reap/Sow](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html), [Monitor](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html), and others, however, as noted above, the example assume mostly a symbolic variable that is given a range rather than a recursive function with a value passed in. It is not clear to me how to use these tools for the case of a recursive function such as the `gcd` example above where a value is passed into the function and the desired behaviour is to monitor / accumulate transformations of a function variable.

What would be the correct way to:

1. Accumulate a list of intermediate values for variable `x` in `gcd[x, y]` as this
   variable is updated through successive recursive calls;
2. Plot these intermediate values of `x` to visualise how the function iterates towards a final solution?

Comment: What's the problem with `gcd[x_, y_] := (Sow@x; If[Equal[y, 0], x, gcd[y, Mod[x, y]]])`, `Reap@gcd[4, 16]`?

Comment: Thanks @LukasLang. I get a syntax error with this statement: Syntax::tsntxi: "gcd[x_,y_]:=(Sow@x;If[Equal[y,0],x,gcd[y,Mod[x,y]]]),Reap@gcd[4,16]" is incomplete; more input is needed. Also, I was not looking to embed the monitoring in the function itself. Rather, I was looking for a way to wrap the function and call specific values to be able to produce a list of intermediate values for x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
Cases[Trace[gcd[4, 16]], gcd[x_, _] :> x, All]
(* {4, 16, 4} *)
```

This should work in most simple cases. It extracts the relevant parameters from the calls listed in the output of `Trace`. For very long traces with a lot of irrelevant stuff, this might not be very efficient however. We can improve this by supplying a filter to `Trace`:

```
Cases[Trace[gcd[4, 16], gcd], gcd[x_, _] :> x, All]
(* {4, 16, 4} *)
```

Comment: Many thanks, I did not know about the Cases function - this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.